# Why react isn't working without CDN links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

friends
The problem with me is that react works only in case of CDN links added to the html file,
but when I remove CDN links and use import statement , the app does not work
here is my code

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>React</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Eslam</h1>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: Do you bundle your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the file locally:

When you open an HTML file locally, it isn't on a server, and therefore `import` statements won't work.

To run your code on a local server, you can use a bunder, but most depend on NodeJS being installed, so if it isn't, go ahead and [install it.](https://nodejs.org)

---

If you are opening the file on a server:

You can use a combination of CDN links and `import` statements:

```js
import React from "unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js";
import ReactDOM from "unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Eslam</h1>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Or, **if you're using a bundler** such as [Parcel](https://parceljs.org), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org), or [Vite](https://vitejs.org), make sure you have the packages `react` and `react-dom` installed in `node_modules` (or etc. if you use yarn PnP):

```
$ # in the terminal (assuming you have node and npm installed-if you don't, 
$ # do yourself a favor and install them because this won't work w/o it)
$ npm install react
$ npm install react-dom
```

Comment: I have already installed node.js and npm , and I have the packages react and react-dom installed in the node_modelus.
I tried to use CDN links with import statement as you mentioned
But there is nothing show on the screen or the console

Comment: @EslamAshraf If you are installing those in node_modules, you need to use a bundler such as the ones I mentioned in order to use them on the browser.